# How to trace value from browser in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook api in application. I have to fetch wall value. I went through the online documentation. When I am giving access token value I am seeing lots of text which are appearing on browser. I have to trace those value in my application.

Opening http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ URl and I am seeing values when I am clicking on link associated with title "Profile feed (Wall)".

How will I do this ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the delegate:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
```

The result of your request is in JSON so it should be fairly easy to use (you can do a `NSLog(@"resut is: %@", result)` ) to see it in detail.

Comment: Will I write like this   [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed?access_token=2227470867|2.AQAP5FnMgBdqogw4.3600.1308661200.0-100002464601210|xZrLrQ9CT0V55lX2JGq3rG2l_2B" andDelegate:self];   to call for browser ?

Comment: Ok I am getting on console. Here result is containing lots of information how will I parse for "Message" only ?

Comment: [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andDelegate:self]; this is the exact call